# Could not create mock object of my own class

Tags: android

I Have written simple app to mock String but when i am running, i am  getting following error:

```
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Start Processing Annotations
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Processing [public void testObject() ]
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Adding Class to Mocking List: java.lang.String
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Found 1 classes to mock
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Mocking class java.lang.String
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Found 0 mocked classes to save
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Finished Processing Mocks
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Start Processing Annotations
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Processing []
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Found 0 classes to mock
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Found 0 mocked classes to save
30 Mar, 2012 2:32:19 PM - NOTE : Finished Processing Mocks
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Start Processing Annotations
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Processing [public void testObject() ]
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Adding Class to Mocking List: java.lang.String
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Found 1 classes to mock
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Mocking class java.lang.String
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Found 0 mocked classes to save
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Finished Processing Mocks
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Start Processing Annotations
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Processing []
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Found 0 classes to mock
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Found 0 mocked classes to save
30 Mar, 2012 2:34:51 PM - NOTE : Finished Processing Mocks
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Start Processing Annotations
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Processing [public void testObject() ]
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Adding Class to Mocking List: java.lang.String
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Found 1 classes to mock
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Mocking class java.lang.String
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Found 0 mocked classes to save
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Finished Processing Mocks
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Start Processing Annotations
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Processing []
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Found 0 classes to mock
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Found 0 mocked classes to save
30 Mar, 2012 2:35:20 PM - NOTE : Finished Processing Mocks
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I am probably late with this answer but I would say it cannot be mocked since the String class is final.